# Close hamburger menu after click

Tags: javascript, html

I have a hamburger menu which is almost complete with just 1 bug/issue that I can't figure out. My nav links to different areas on the home page. So on the home page the user can click a nav link which would instantly take them down to the desired location on the page. My issue comes as there is no loading so once the user clicks on the nav link they are brought to the location but the dropdown menu will not close. Thanks for the help and please let me know if  any other information is needed!

**HTML / PHP:**

```
<button class="header__hamburger">
                            <i class="icon-hamburger"></i>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="header__mobile-menu mobile-menu">
                <div class="mobile-menu__body">
                    <div class="mobile-menu__wrapper">
                                                     

                        <a href="<?php echo esc_url(home_url('/')); ?>" class="mobile-menu__logo logo">
                            <?php if (!empty(mvt_get_option('hd-logo'))) { ?>
                            
                          <img src="<?php echo esc_url(mvt_get_option('hd-logo')); ?>" alt="logo" class="logo__img">      
                                
                            <?php } else { ?>
                                <img style="float: left;" src="<?php echo esc_url(mvt_get_option('logo')); ?>" alt="logo" class="logo__img">
                                <p style="color:#bc9355; font-family: "Sofia", "Courier New";>Fine Style  <span style="color:#ffffff; font-size:60%;                                    margin-left: 23%;" >Hair Salon</span></p>   
                            <?php } ?>
                        </a>
                        <div class="mobile-menu__close">
                            <i class="icon-close"></i>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <?php if (has_nav_menu('mobile_menu')) : ?>
                        <nav class="mobile-menu__nav">
                            <?php wp_nav_menu(array(
                                'theme_location'  => 'mobile_menu',
                                'container'       => 'ul',
                                'menu_class'      => 'mobile-menu__list',
                            )); ?>
                        </nav>
                    <?php endif; ?>
            <div class="js-form">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- END MODAL WINDOW -->

<?php wp_footer(); ?>

</body>

</html>
```

**CSS**

```
.header .header__topBar .header__body .header__hamburger {
  display: none;
  width: 30px;
  height: 16px;
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
  background: none;
}
@media (max-width: 767.98px) {
  .header .header__topBar .header__body .header__hamburger {
    display: block;
  }

}
.header .header__topBar .header__body .header__hamburger i {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 16px;
}


.header .header__mobile-menu.mobile-menu {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #111111;
  transform: translateY(-100%);
  transition: transform 0.5s ease;
  overflow: auto;
  z-index: 100000;
}
.header .header__mobile-menu.mobile-menu._active {
  
    transform: translateY(0);
    

}
.header .header__mobile-menu.mobile-menu .mobile-menu__body {
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 24px 20px;
}
.header .header__mobile-menu.mobile-menu .mobile-menu__body .mobile-menu__wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  margin-bottom: 115px;
}
.header .header__mobile-menu.mobile-menu .mobile-menu__body .mobile-menu__wrapper .mobile-menu__close {
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.header .header__mobile-menu.mobile-menu .mobile-menu__body .mobile-menu__nav .mobile-menu__list {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}
.header .header__mobile-menu.mobile-menu .mobile-menu__body .mobile-menu__nav .mobile-menu__list li:not(:last-child) {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.header .header__mobile-menu.mobile-menu .mobile-menu__body .mobile-menu__nav .mobile-menu__list li a {
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

I tried to try it with Js but it doesent work.

```
$('.header__mobile-menu').on('click', function () {
  $('.mobile-menu__body').addClass('open');
});

$( '.mobile-menu__body a' ).on("click", function(){
  $('.mobile-menu__body').removeClass('open');
});
```

Comment: This question has nothing to do with `PHP`. Please post the generated HTML in order to create a [mre]

Comment: as already pointed out .. please don't share the php page but the actual html because it's hard to say how those conditions will be evaluated with no context. And possibly spend some time to make it a live snippet that doesn't require any guess so it will reduce the effort for people trying to solve your problem

Comment: Welcome! My guess is because the `click` event is bubbling up on the `.mobile-menu__body a` to the `.header__mobile_menu`. So, your `removeClass` is working, but the `addClass` is also firing because your `.mobile-menu__body a` elements are **children** of the `.header__mobile-menu` element. Not sure why you are opening the menu when clicking on the header. You should probably move your `open` event to `.header__hamburger` instead.

Answer (score 0):

To close the mobile menu when a user clicks on a navigation link within it, you can use JavaScript. However, it seems like there is an issue with the code you provided. You are trying to add and remove the 'open' class from the .mobile-menu__body element, but the class names and structure in your HTML/CSS don't align with this approach. You can try this code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 $('.header__mobile-menu').on('click', function () {
 $(this).toggleClass('_active'); // Toggle the '_active' class on the '.header__mobile-menu' element
  });
$('.mobile-menu__list a').on('click', function () {
$('.header__mobile-menu').removeClass('_active'); // Close the mobile menu by removing '_active' class
 });
});
```